# Fastest way to dump remote Hive table to local machine?

Tags: hadoop, hive, dump

Any suggestion?

(There is no need to preserve table scheme. Any format will be OK)

Comment: Try this: hive -e 'select * from Table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.txt

Comment: @srikanth how when remote hive?

Comment: use hive -h ipaddress -p port  -e 'select * from Table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > outputfile.txt

Comment: @srikanth `Unrecognized option: -h`

Comment: I tried using beeline. but encountered OOM exception. Hive table is very big(50M over rows). It seems like Hive saves its data to the memory first(for mapper).